# Apache doesn't start after switching to worker mpm

Tags: apache, centos, lamp, centos7

I have got a centOS7 server and I've successfully installed LAMP stack , but i've decided to use worker mpm instead of prefork mpm , when i commented this :

```
#LoadModule mpm_prefork_module modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
```

and uncommented this :

```
LoadModule mpm_worker_module modules/mod_mpm_worker.so
```

after i have switched to worker and i tried to restart apache , i get the following error :

```
Job for httpd.service failed. See 'systemctl status httpd.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

what should I do to start apache with worker mpm ?

Answer (score 1):

Usually the MPM you use is decided at compile time so it's usually not possible to change without recompiling Apache.

See here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mpm.html

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly change apache MPM as it is fixed at compile time only. As you are using LAMP and if you want to use Apache Worker MPM than configure  Apache MPM Worker with PHP-FPM.

Refer to [Apache MPM Worker with PHP-FPM](https://www.garron.me/en/linux/apache-mpm-worker-php-fpm-mysql-centos.html)